# How to express this with "extra" words? "You can't just do whatever ya want"

Tags: traducción, gramática

En Ingles:
"Hey, you know, you can't just go around doing whatever you feel like and live however you want"

Soy un principiante, y estoy aprendiendo el modo de subjuntivo ahora.
Parece ser que esta frase no es suficiente - "No puedes hacer lo que quieras".

En Ingles... How do you express that first scentence, using "filler" words, using a "typical" Latin American (Mexico) dialect?

Comment: Maybe ‘no puedes hacer lo que te venga en gana/ganas’ or ‘te entre en gana/ganas’

Comment: You've got a typo in "No puedes hace lo que quieras". It should be "hacer" there. And that's not an accurate translation. In "plain" Spanish the whole sentence would be: "Ey, sabes, no puedes ir por ahí haciendo lo que que quieras y viviendo como te apetezca". "Lo que te venga en gana" instead of "lo que quieras", as Traveller pointed, could be used in Spain too.

Comment: Not sure how much this will help but the Rolling Stones song "You can't always get what you want" is, according to Wikipedia, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can%27t_Always_Get_What_You_Want#  «No siempre puedes conseguir lo que deseas»

Comment: "Hey, you know, you can't just go around doing whatever you feel like and liv**ing** however you want". Oye or Mira, **no puedes irte por allí haciendo lo que te da la gana** y viviendo como te paresca.

Comment: @Lambie "irte por allí" doesn't seem idiomatic to me. Using almost the same words, check my suggested translation: "ir por ahí". There is a typo in "paresca". Totally ok with "lo que te da la gana".

Comment: Acabo de pedir a mi esposa (Sevillano puro) y me dice que irse por ahi está bien. allí es un error de tipografia. Nada mas.

Comment: @Lambie No. [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irte+por+all%C3%AD%2Cirte+por+ah%C3%AD%2C+ir+por+ah%C3%AD%2C+ir+por+all%C3%AD&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irte+por+all%C3%AD%2Cirte+por+ah%C3%AD%2C+ir+por+ah%C3%AD%2C+ir+por+all%C3%AD&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Pizzaguy07 YES: I said allí in my comment was an error. It should be: ahí in my comment. Other than that: https://elcomercio.pe/respuestas/ahi-escribe-diccionario-palabras-significado-rae-real-academia-espanola-ortografia-nnda-nnlt-noticia-547541-noticia/

Comment: @Lambie No. "Ir**te** por ahí/allí" is not idiomatic. Look at the ngrams and you will see that "**ir** por ahí/allí" is by far more used

Comment: @Pizzaguy07 Ngrams does not record spoken forms per se. Irse por ahí/allí is completely grammatical. 
Óscar Lezameta
ÓSCAR LEZAMETA olezameta@huelvainformacion.es
Irse por ahí - Title from a Spanish journalist. Do you even actually speak Spanish? I wonder...

Comment: "**Me encanta que puedas ir por ahi a donde tu quieras , es decir, que te puedes saltar la mision que estes haciendo  y irte por ahi a subir niveles para nuestros queridos pokémons**". https://6adescubriendoelfinal.blogspot.com/